# How to use Swift async/await in parallel

Tags: ios, swift, async-await

Consider the code below:

```
class UserProfile
{
    private var img: UIImage? {
       didSet { /* update ui */ }
    }
    private var bio: String? {
       didSet { /* update ui */ }
    }

    private func loadImage() async -> UIImage? {
        // ... 
    }

    private func loadBio() async -> String? {
        // ...
    }

    public func loadData() async {
        async let img = loadImage()
        async let bio = loadBio()

        self.img = await img
        self.bio = await bio
    }
}
```

While this one does run the loading routines in parallel, assigning the results is synchronized: `self.bio` will always be assigned after `self.img`. This means the UI for the bio will have to wait for the image to be loaded. I would like these to be decoupled from each other. Completion handlers would have been ideal here, but we're using the async API. How do I make it so the assignment happens in the order of completion?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you could try something like this:

```
func loadData() async {
    await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
        group.addTask { self.img = await loadImage() }
        group.addTask { self.bio = await loadBio() }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I believe using tuples would solve this:

`(self.img, self.bio) = await (img, bio)`