# Swift Concurrency: `async let` strange behaviour on Simulators

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

I run the following code snippet and expect `loadFromNetwork` and `loadFromDB` to be run in parallel.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        Task {
            async let networkData = loadFromNetwork()
            async let dbData = loadFromDB()
            await print("\(networkData) \(dbData)")
        }
    }
}

func loadFromNetwork() async -> String {
    print("loadFromNetwork started \(Thread.current)")
    // (0...10000000).forEach { String($0) }
    sleep(3)
    print("loadFromNetwork finished")
    return "Network Data"
}

func loadFromDB() async -> String {
    print("loadFromDB started \(Thread.current)")
    // (0...10000000).forEach { String($0) }
    sleep(1)
    print("loadFromDB finished")
    return "DB Data"
}
```

But I see that `loadFromNetwork` and `loadFromDB` run sequently on the same background thread. Why does it happen?

```
loadFromNetwork started <NSThread: 0x6000008d7180>{number = 3, name = (null)}
loadFromNetwork finished
loadFromDB started <NSThread: 0x6000008d7180>{number = 3, name = (null)}
loadFromDB finished
Network Data DB Data
```

**UPDATE**

I've found that this happens only on Simulators. I've tested on iPhone 13 Pro Max and iPhone 12 Prod Max. On my iPhone 7 device all works good. I've updated the title.

```
loadFromNetwork started <NSThread: 0x2834cc080>{number = 3, name = (null)}
loadFromDB started <NSThread: 0x2834c2280>{number = 5, name = (null)}
loadFromDB finished
loadFromNetwork finished
Network Data DB Data
```

Comment: It's because your test is flawed.

Comment: I feel so :) How to achieve parallel work in this case ?

Comment: see my answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69491806/how-to-use-swift-async-await-in-parallel/69493144#69493144

Comment: Make them 2 separate `Task`

Answer (score 1):

Your test is flawed. Don't mix threads and thread-sleep, on the one hand, with structured concurrency, on the other. Your use of `sleep` *blocks*. The whole point of structured concurrency `await` is that it *doesn't* block.

Here's a rewrite that tests properly:

```
extension Task where Success == Never, Failure == Never {
    static func sleep(_ seconds:Double) async {
        await self.sleep(UInt64(seconds * 1_000_000_000))
    }
    static func sleepThrowing(_ seconds:Double) async throws {
        try await self.sleep(nanoseconds: UInt64(seconds * 1_000_000_000))
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Task {
            async let networkData = loadFromNetwork()
            async let dbData = loadFromDB()
            await print("\(networkData) \(dbData)")
        }
    }
}

func loadFromNetwork() async -> String {
    print("loadFromNetwork started \(Thread.current)")
    await Task.sleep(3.0)
    print("loadFromNetwork finished")
    return "Network Data"
}

func loadFromDB() async -> String {
    await Task.sleep(1.0)
    print("loadFromDB started \(Thread.current)")
    await Task.sleep(1.0)
    print("loadFromDB finished")
    return "DB Data"
}
```

My output is:

```
loadFromNetwork started <NSThread: 0x60000198bb40>{number = 5, name = (null)}
loadFromDB started <NSThread: 0x600001999500>{number = 7, name = (null)}
loadFromDB finished
loadFromNetwork finished
Network Data DB Data
```

As you can see, the subtasks are interleaved (concurrent), just as you desire.

Even so, looking at the thread number is still wrong. The system is perfectly free to use the same thread for all the different parts of these subtasks. For instance, if I delete the first sleep from `loadFromDB`, I get:

```
loadFromNetwork started <NSThread: 0x600002bf2480>{number = 7, name = (null)}
loadFromDB started <NSThread: 0x600002bf2480>{number = 7, name = (null)}
loadFromDB finished
loadFromNetwork finished
Network Data DB Data
```

So at least at the start they were using the same thread — and why not? We are still getting concurrency, which is all that matters. You shouldn't be peeking at what thread we are "on".

(I do call `Thread.isMainThread` sometimes just to make sure of how the context is being switched, but even that can risk generating a Heisenbug.)

Comment: But what if we change `sleep` with real execution let's say `(0...10000000).forEach { String($0) }`. There is no parallel work in this case.

Comment: You will if your lengthy task does a periodic `yield` (or a deeper `await` of course). Otherwise where is the place for concurrency?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please have a look at my update section above. I figured out that this issue happens only on Simulators. Not sure whether that's a bug or just kind of Simulator optimisation.

Comment: Great testing, upvoted. I've no idea about that part; just in case, I recommend filing a bug (I've filed quite a few bugs on structured concurrency, it isn't really baked yet).