# How can I use parallelism in Swift to execute a method on a list of objects?

Tags: swift, loops, parallel-processing

I have a list of objects and I'm currently looping over the list and executing a method for each of those objects like this:

```
var houses = [House]()
for house in houses {
    house.price = calculateHousePrice(house: house)
}
// continue here once all the prices have been calculated
```

Calculating the house price takes a long time, and is not dependent on the result of other calculations.

How can I use parallelism in Swift to speed this loop up?
I've had a look at GCD, but I'm new to Swift and not sure what I should be using.

I've tried this:

```
for house in houses {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [self] in
        house.price = calculateHousePrice(house: house)
    }
}
// continue here once all the prices have been calculated
```

but the loop completes before all the task have completed.

Changing `async` to `sync` helps, but I feel that I'm no better off than with the initial code.

Comment: This is a great use case for `async`/`await` with/without with `TaskGroup`

Comment: GCD is an intermediate layer of abstraction, above working with raw threads/locks, and below Tasks and TaskGroups in the new Swift Concurrency system. The way you're using it is totally find. "the loop completes before all the task have completed" Yep, that's to be expected. With GCD, your two options are to: 1) Use a DispatchGroup to wait until all the tasks finish (this is **very** bad, because it blocks the queue. Don't do it, I only mention it so I can tell you not to use it lol), 2) Use a dispatch queue to notify you when done, 3) Use a completion handler to be informed of when it's done

Comment: The modern Swift concurrency tools are probably the best suited for the job, and have by far the nicest ergonomics.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Swift async/await in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69491806/how-to-use-swift-async-await-in-parallel)